# Removing/Changing the "mailed by" header in Salesforce emails

Tags: email

Emails we send from Salesforce have the mailby with a lot of numbers @salesforce.com. Is there a way so that this doesn't show, or change it to be our company domain?

[image]

Comment: If you have your own SMTP server you could try using it to relay the emails. See [Setting Up Email Relaying](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_relay.htm&language=en_US). I'm not certain, but I suspect this would alter the mailed-by header.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I learned we are on the free version of Google biz apps, and can't set up SMTP relay until we start paying. Good to know for that time though, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

@paul I recommend the use of org wide email address. Just define the email adress in the organization and at the time of sending an email set the desired org wide address for the email.

Comment: Hi Mukul,
Can you help me with this please as you said we need to configure the Org Wide Email.

Answer (score 1):

You should really look into setting up your email relay to use Google. You must use the paid version of Google Apps. Find the detailed instructions here: http://www.grooveapp.com/blog/salesforce-remove-via-gmail/